# Soviet Union, state capitalism and socialism

Tags: socialism, soviet-union

I believe that the soviet union really wasn't socialism, it was redefined to mean state capitalism. And I think state capitalism and socialism are inconsistent. Socialism always meant that workers control their workplace so it is more a theory of economics and not a political ideology. I know that there are a lot of sources from prominent marxists and socialists at that time who would agree with me. But I think these guys are marginalized.

Is there any major and credible study that agrees with me that the soviet union (or other nominally self described "socialist" governments) was/were not socialist?

edit/ Ok since my question wasn't answered (the only answer was that the soviet union was socialist) I reframe my question into: What "reliable" sources exist, that say that the soviet union wasn't socialist?(except Chomsky)

Comment: The soviet union was communist, not socialist. (or at least claimed to be).

Comment: The state owned MOST means of production in USSR (with minor caveats not worth mentioning), so it was socialist by that definition. Capitalism is defined by means of production being owned by capital investors. </ghost_of>

Comment: This question [is asked](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27076/soviet-union-state-capitalism-and-socialism) on two sites, so it probably should be closed at least once.

Comment: Socialism is when workers own the means of production, socialism doesn't need a government at all.

Comment: Question demonstrates a poor understanding of the academic definitions of socialism and capitalism, further complicated by a reliance on belief, opinion, and unspecified metrics.

Comment: @JonnyPython [I've created the question you should have asked](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/what-are-the-ideological-differences-between-the-soviet-union-and-noam-chomsky).

Comment: The Soviet Union itself claimed to be socialist (that's what the 2nd S in the USSR) stands for. So proving otherwise would entail some definition of socialism which they didn't agree with. (Certainly not [state socialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_socialism)). You might be confusing this issue with [whether they implemented communism](https://www.umass.edu/pubaffs/chronicle/archives/02/10-11/economics.html). O

Answer (score 7):

The problem with word definitions in politics is that people tend to interpret them vastly different. A word has the meaning people give to it. So people often try to change and shift the definitions of words to repurpose them as it fits their agenda. That means for many political ideologies there are different, often contradicting, definitions.

[The Merriam Webster dictionary defines Socialism as this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socialism):

> **Simple Definition of socialism**
>
> a way of organizing a society in which major industries are owned and controlled by the government rather than by individual people and companies
>
> **Full Definition of socialism**
>
> 1. any of various economic and political theories advocating collective or governmental ownership and administration of the means of production and distribution of goods
> 2. - a: system of society or group living in which there is no private property,
>    - b:  a system or condition of society in which the means of production are owned and controlled by the state
> 3. a stage of society in Marxist theory transitional between capitalism and communism and distinguished by unequal distribution of goods and pay according to work done

As you can see these are four different ways to define socialism which are partially overlapping and partially contradicting. Let's see how they fitted the Soviet Union.

> Simple definition: way of organizing a society in which major industries are owned and controlled by the government rather than by individual people and companies

Applies. Most industry in the USSR was state-owned.

> 1: any of various economic and political theories advocating collective or governmental ownership and administration of the means of production and distribution of goods

Collective? Not really. [The USSR collectivized the agriculture sector quite a lot in the 30s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectivization_in_the_Soviet_Union), but in practice it just increased government control and reduced the self-determination rights of the farmers instead of improving them. Government ownership? Applies to most other industries, as explained in the last point.

> 2a: system of society or group living in which there is no private property

There was private property in the Soviet Union, but there were regulations about what could and could not be owned by private people. Such restrictions usually exist in any country, but while most non-socialist countries mostly ban the possession of certain items for safety reasons (weapons, drugs, hazardous chemicals...), the USSR also did it for property because it had economical value (housing, factories, farmland...).

> 2b: a system or condition of society in which the means of production are owned and controlled by the state

This is a stronger form of the simple definition and the definition 1. Mostly applies. Most means of production were controlled by the state, but not all of them.

> 3. a stage of society in Marxist theory transitional between capitalism and communism and distinguished by unequal distribution of goods and pay according to work done

There definitely was an unequal distribution of goods and pay. One could argue that the totalitarian Soviet Union regime was a necessary step on the road to true Communism which was never completed. But because the Soviet Union doesn't exist anymore, we can only speculate if the Soviet Union would have ever transited to Communism if it had the chance or if it would have developed in a different direction.

**Summary:** The Soviet Union was socialist according to most of the possible interpretations of the term.

> Socialism always meant that workers control their workplace.

The system you are talking about here is often referred to as [Syndicalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndicalism). And the variant of it which "doesn't need a government at all" is called [Anarcho-Syndicalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-syndicalism).

Comment: Alright, so where has Chomsky the idea from that socialism means exactly what I described? And that the soviet union was the exact opposite of socialism? And not only Chomsky says this. There is a real debate if the SU was socialism or in fact state capitalism. I want to know the truth and not propaganda.

Comment: @JonnyPython I already told you: The truth about the definition of a word depends on who uses it. Socialism for Chomsky means something different than it meant for Stalin which is again something different than what Marx, Mao, Lenin, Guevera, Trotzky or Il-sung meant when they used the word. There is no consensus about the "true" meaning of the word "socialism". That's why there are so many terms for sub-categories.

Comment: Yes no consensus. But still you think it's when the state owns everything. You are contradicting yourself here sry. I think the nominally socialist states called themself socialist to defame socialism. They also called themselfs democracy. What would that mean for democracy?

Comment: *"I think the nominally socialist states called themself socialist to defame socialism"* - that thought makes no sense. Why would you assign a label to yourself and then defame that label? That would mean to defame yourself. And *democracy*, by the way, is a term which is just as ill-defined and subjective as *socialism*.

Comment: Sry my mistake. I think people like Lenin used it because it appealed to the people and had a good reputation in the past, but redefined it to mean state capitalism and the SU had nothing to do with free people and socialism and social justice how can a top down authoritarian state be consistent with all of that? The USA then used the SU to defame socialism. And all of that was criticised by people on the left at that time.

Comment: @JonnyPython what are you really looking for, here? Your questions asks if the USSR can be considered socialist. The answer provides you with a definition from a well-known source and compares that definition to historical facts.

Comment: @JonnyPython, maybe you're getting a little too bogged down in terminology. What matters is specific policies and ideas, not the words we use to describe the whole. It complicates it, but there's really no other way that makes any sense.

Comment: @JonnyPython - your comment is pure projection, sorry. What you *seem* to WANT (and by the way, same thing that Chomsky wants, and why he said what he said), is to associate Capitalism with something bad, both directly (by saying "bad Soviet Union had it") and indirectly (by saying "Socialism is opposit of Capitalism, and it is good, and the only reason people say it isn't good - which is USSR example - is incorrect because USSR didn't actually have socialism"). Now, you're projecting the same approach onto people who say the opposite.....

Comment: @JonnyPython - ... The only difference between you/Chomsky and what Philipp said is that Philipp's statement is actually backing up the general vague statement (X is/isn't socialism/capitalism) with facts.

Comment: BTW, 2a is not entirely correct.  While "there was private property in the Soviet Union" as a broad statement is true, a LOT of property wasn't allowed to be private if you look into details. You couldn't own housing (at least in urban setting) or land. You couldn't own a small business (after N.E.P. and before Gorbachyov).

Comment: @user4012 I elaborated a bit on point 2a.

Comment: I edited my question.